# Scalar directions other than an angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I can think of two obvious, simple ways to express a direction on the two-dimensional plane: as an angle, or as a direction vector (normalized or not).

When doing computational geometry, direction vectors are nice in that they're very simple to calculate when comparing two positions as measured in ordinary Cartesian coordinates (especially when there's no need to normalize it), but less nice in that they need to be expressed as multiple scalars. Angles are nice in that they're just a simple, scalar quantity, but conversion between Cartesian coordinates and angles are less than trivial.

Which got me wondering: Is there another way to express directions as a simple scalar that is not so awkward to relate to Cartesian coordinates as angles are? I can't immediately think of any, but I can't say I've been able to prove that one cannot exist, either. I wouldn't be surprised if there is some well-known metric that I just haven't heard of, but I haven't been able to find one.

Slopes seem to come close, if it weren't for the obvious deficiency of only being able to express less than half of an arc.

Comment: One can define a notion of "slope of half of the angle", which works for all directions in the plane except for one but like slopes is still related to Cartesian coordinates by simple rational functions---in fact, this idea is closely related to the Weierstraß substitution in elementary integral calculus.

Comment: I think that in 2D, the situation is poor (@Travis is right when saying that there is an interest to work with half of the angle). I advise you to turn to 3D (practical issues are very often in 3D!): have a look 1) to interesting coordinates called Plucker coordinates 2) to the emerging field called "Geometric algebra" with, in particular a rôle played  by Clifford spaces.